# Translating weak encryption algorithm from PHP to Coldfusion or Java

Tags: java, php, coldfusion

I'm working with someone that is having me 'encrypt' some text I send to his webservice using the function listed below. I've tried to translate these into Coldfusion but my output doesn't match his version. I would rather simply use AES 256 and call it a day, but I literally have no choice as this is what they use. Can someone please help me translate this into either Coldfusion or Java.

```
function encrypt($string, $key) {
  $result = '';
  for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
    $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
    $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
    $char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar));
    $result.=$char;
}

  return base64_encode($result);
}

function decrypt($string, $key) {
  $result = '';
  $string = base64_decode($string);

  for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) {
    $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
    $keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1);
    $char = chr(ord($char)-ord($keychar));
    $result.=$char;
  }

    return $result;
}
```

My Coldfusion versions:

```
function hideText(argsString, key) {
  var result = '';
  for(i=1; i <= len(argsString); i++) {
    char = mid(argsString, i, 1);
    keychar = mid(key, i, 1);
    char = asc(ord(char) & ord(keychar));
    result &= char;
  }
    return toBase64(result);
}

function unHideText(argsString, key) {
  result = '';
  string = toString( ToBinary( argsString ) );

  for(i=1; i<= strlen(argsString); i++) {
    char = mid(argsString, i, 1);
    keychar = mid(key, i, 1);
    char = asc(ord(char) - ord(keychar));
    result &= char;
  }
    return result;
}

function ord(any argString){
    return Left(argString, 1);
}
```

My CF version isn't using the % as I think that might just evaluate to the same thing as **i** does anyway - and it actually produces a result without it. Though I may be missing ***why*** it was there in the first place. Anyone use both PHP and CF have any insight into a better translation? If its easier to explain in java I'm perfectly comfortable with that as well.

Comment: php [`ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) is not equivalent to what you have in CF.

Comment: @ElefantPhave ord() returns the 'ascii value of a character'. I am getting the first char and using it inside a asc() function, which I think returns the ascii value. Is that wrong? Or are you saying I should put the entire thing in a function?

Comment: @ialexander That's not what the php version is doing. It's getting the ASCII value of each character, adding them together, and then returns the new character

Comment: I see. I read it too fast. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: Now that you have it figured out, do not forget to `var` scope all of the function local variables to avoid conflicts.  Also, though I realize the functions are rewrites of the original code, you might want to avoid variable names like "string" as they are potential keywords.

Comment: @Leigh Duly noted. Var scope everything and better variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your `ord` function.

This line in your CF:

```
char = asc(ord(char) & ord(keychar));
```

should be:

```
char = Chr(Asc(char) + Asc(keychar));
```